# SVN Merge resolve conflicts with incoming versions

Tags: svn, merge

I am writing a perl script where I do merge from a branch to the trunk using this command:

```
svn merge $sourceBranchURL -r 0:$revision
```

Now what I want is, if any conflict occurs, then I want it to take the incoming version.

```
svn merge $sourceBranchURL -r 0:$revision resolve --accept base
```

Is it the right way of doing it ? If yes, then do I need anyother thing to do like removing? If not then, what is the right way of doing it?